# Angular JS Adding code snippet in JSON and trying to render in Front END just for Display

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to Add Code Snippet IN JSON to Display in Front END as attached in the image.

can you please advice can we add ?

```
[
     {
       "codesnippet" : "var name = "Developers Choice"
                        var age = 28;
                        console.log(name) //Developers Choice
                        undefined //age is undefined"
     }
    ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing a generic text in JSON, you need to escape the `"` and `<line break>` characters. That would give :

```
[
  {
    "codesnippet" : "var name = \"Developers Choice\"\nvar age = 28;\nconsole.log(name) //Developers Choice\nundefined //age is undefined"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% if I know what you are asking but at first glance you are missing a semicolon after `var name = "Developers Choice"`

Comment: I guess OP means if they can output it in the browser as showed on the printscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible to do with CSS and the `<code>` tag for example.
The `<code>` tag is a phrase tag. It defines a piece of computer code.

**Tip:** This tag is not deprecated, but it is possible to achieve richer effect with CSS.

**All phrase tags:**

**Tag   Description**

```
<em>    Renders as emphasized text
<strong>Defines important text
<code>  Defines a piece of computer code
<samp>  Defines sample output from a computer program
<kbd>   Defines keyboard input
<var>   Defines a variableThe <code> tag is a phrase tag. It defines a piece of computer code.
```